# TCPDF, Text always italic

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Im using TCPDF to automatically generate dynamic PDFs. The problem i am having is that everytime i try and render any sort of text, be that using `writeHTML()` or `MultiCell()`, or any other text function for that matter. They all seem to have the default text style of italic. And just to clarify, when setting the font i have specified that the style should be 'normal'.

Any have any idea how to fix this, Thanks Scott

Comment: Are you using a builtin or TTF font?

Comment: Show your code where you set up font

Comment: Sorry guys, managed to fix it now, Thanks Though.

Comment: Im having another problem though. What methods does it offer to set text colour. None of the HTML Method seem to accept the like of `color='#FFF'` or `style='color: #FFF;'`

Comment: _Sorry guys, managed to fix it now_ - what was the problem? (It's always good practise to add your own answer if you solve it yourself. It might be useful for someone else, and can be considered the 'price' of asking for help).

Comment: The default setting was for some reason not being properly reset, i had to declare the font as Italic and then non italic for it to work.